# Definition of special $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

I would like to know if there is a standard definition for finite special $p$-groups. I would have two questions related to this:

1. In some sources (for instance, Gorenstein's *Finite groups*), it is said that a $p$-group $P$ is special if $P$ is elementary abelian or $P$ is of class 2 and $P'=Z(P)=\Phi(P)$ is elementary abelian. In the latter case, it won't matter if we specifically say that $P$ is of class 2. However, in Berkovich & Janko's *Groups of Prime Power Order* (vol. 3), a special $p$-group would be a non-abelian $p$-group $P$ such that $P'=Z(P)=\Phi(P)$ is elementary abelian. So, my question would be if there is a specific reason for which the abelian case is dropped in the latter reference?
2. For the non-abelian case, would it be sufficient to say that a $p$-group $P$ is special if the condition $P'=Z(P)=\Phi(P)$ holds (without specifying that the 3 subgroups are elementary abelian)? If so, how can we prove that $P'=Z(P)=\Phi(P)$ implies that $P'$ (or $Z(G)$ or $\Phi(P)$) is elementary abelian? We know that $P/\Phi(P)=P/Z(P)=P/P'$ is elementary abelian by the properties of the Frattini subgroup.

Thank you for considering these questions!

Comment: Yes, $P/Z(G)$ elementary abelian implies $P'$ is elementary abelian. This follows from the fact that commutators are bilinear in groups of class $2$.

Comment: Berkovich can be... idiosyncratic. One reason to include the abelian case is that then you can probably state theorems in general without specifying non-abelianness (you want the abelianization to be elementary abelian, for example). Berkovich is mostly interested in classification schemes of nilpotent groups, and the abelian groups are the "easy" case that he almost never considers separately, so it would not be a surprise if he just doesn't care about the abelian case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2: if $P'=Z(P)=\Phi(P)$, then they are all elementary abelian.

Indeed, because $P'=Z(P)$, $P$ will be of class two (we are assuming non-abelian), and so the commutator bracket is bilinear.

Since $\Phi(P)$ contains all $p$th powers and equals the center, it follows that all $p$th powers are central.

Now, $P'$ is generated by elements of the form $[x,y]$, $x,y\in P$. Then we have
$$[x,y]^p = [x^p,y] = e$$
since $x^p\in \Phi(P)=Z(P)$. Thus, $P'$ is abelian and generated by elements of exponent $p$, so it is elementary abelian, which is what we wanted to show.